# How to determine if a user has capitalized a string input or not in C#?

Tags: c#, string, input, tolower

This is my first question here!

I'm working on a `C#` coding assignment for college where the player inputs different actions and results of their actions are displayed in the console. Until now, I have simply been saying

`(if firstInput == "Action" || firstInput == "action")`

I have heard that I could simplify this using `string.ToLower()`, but I cannot seem to figure out how to.

Any help on this would be appreciated, and my apologies if it's pretty obvious, I'm a `C#` noob :p

Thanks!

Comment: did you try `if (firstInput.ToLower() == "action")` ?  I mean it appears a super simple and duplicate question from what you post, and code examples are always good

Comment: You can use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.equals?view=netframework-4.7.2 with `StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase`.

Comment: Just don't get bitten by [the Turkey test](http://www.moserware.com/2008/02/does-your-code-pass-turkey-test.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is to convert the input to all lower case, so that you can always compare against a lower case string constant no matter what the user entered

```
if (firstInput.ToLower() == "action") {
    ...
}
```

Examples:

```
"ACTION".ToLower()  ===>  "action"
"Action".ToLower()  ===>  "action"
"action".ToLower()  ===>  "action"
```

Answer (score 1):

If it really matters if the user wrote the first letter in capital letter or not, you might need to compare the strings specifying not to ignore cases.

So, since `"Action" != "action"`, give a try to [String.Equals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.equals?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_String_Equals_System_String_)

```
bool isEqual = String.Equals(x, y, StringComparison.Ordinal);
```

So then, I would perform a `.ToLower()` from the user's input and then compare it with the original input.

Answer (score 0):

`string.ToLower()` returns a new `string` containing all lowercase characters. So your code should read like this:

```
if (firstInput.ToLower() == "action"){
{
```

The `.ToLower()` transforms `firstInput` into an all-lowercase string. When you compare that with an all lowercase string literal for `"action"`, the compare will succeed if `firstInput` contains `"action"` in any upper or lower case form (Action, action, aCtIoN, etc).

It's worth noting that the [Microsoft .Net documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.tolower?view=netframework-4.7.2) tells you how to use `string.ToLower()`. As part of learning how to program in C#, you should get used to checking the Microsoft .Net documentation to learn how to use functionality provided by the framework. The `string.ToLower()` article provides a complete code sample:

```
using System;

public class ToLowerTest {
    public static void Main() {

        string [] info = {"Name", "Title", "Age", "Location", "Gender"};

        Console.WriteLine("The initial values in the array are:");
        foreach (string s in info)
            Console.WriteLine(s);

        Console.WriteLine("{0}The lowercase of these values is:", Environment.NewLine);        

        foreach (string s in info)
            Console.WriteLine(s.ToLower());

    }
}
// The example displays the following output:
//       The initial values in the array are:
//       Name
//       Title
//       Age
//       Location
//       Gender
//       
//       The lowercase of these values is:
//       name
//       title
//       age
//       location
//       gender
```